# Keep current state of data of clicked element in form inputs when updating in React?

Tags: reactjs, forms, axios, state, patch

I am trying to update some data in my React component. The update does work, but to improve the UI/UX, I want the current state of the data that will updated to be in the form inputs before I update.

Currently, when clicking an element to update, the form inputs are blank and you have to completely re-type all form inputs to update.

Instead, I need all form inputs to consist of the current state of the data and not be blank.

> Component with useState hooks, axios.patch method, and input forms

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { getCookie } from "../../../utils/cookies";
import axios from "axios";
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';
import { PencilSquare } from 'react-bootstrap-icons';

export default function UpdateService({ fetchData, id }) {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [desc, setDesc] = useState("");

  const isEnabled = name.length > 0 && desc.length > 0;

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const updateService = async (id: number) => {
     try {
       const JWT = await getCookie("auth");
       const { data } = await axios(
       `/api/serviceType/${id}`, {
       method: "PATCH",
       data: {
        name: name,
        description: desc,
      },
       headers: {
         "Content-Type": "application/json",
         Authorization: JWT,
       },
       });
       setData(data);
       setIsLoading(false);

       // Hides Modal on submission
       setShow(false);
       
     } catch (e) {
       setIsLoading(false);
       alert("error updating data");
     }
  };

  // Table state update on submit
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(data);
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <>
      <PencilSquare onClick={handleShow}/>

      <Modal show={show} backdrop="static" onHide={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Update Service</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <Form onSubmit={() => updateService(id)}>
            <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="exampleForm.ControlInput1">
              <Form.Label>Service Name</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="text"
                value={name}
                placeholder="Service Name"
                autoFocus
                onChange={(e) => {setName(e.target.value)}}
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group
              className="mb-3"
              controlId="exampleForm.ControlTextarea1"
            >
              <Form.Label>Description</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control 
                as="textarea" 
                rows={3}
                placeholder="Please describe this service"
                value={desc}
                onChange={(e) => setDesc(e.target.value)}
                />
            </Form.Group>
          </Form>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="outline-dark" onClick={handleClose}>
            Cancel
          </Button>
          <Button type="submit" variant="dark" onClick={() => updateService(id)} disabled={!isEnabled}>
            Update
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}
```

I've tried using a spread operator within my useState hook but it didn't seem to like how I was passing it in, plus I ran into a few scope related issues as well.

Answer (score 0):

In your `updateService` function just before your request you need to put `e.preventDefault()` to cancel the `<Form>` events from happening. then you can create your own
function to call to handle clearing the inputs when you want like so:

```
const clearFormInputs = () => {
  setName('')
  setDesc('')
}
```